# Происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "спесь"? Какой там корень, и от какого слова оно образовалось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Спесь** - чрезмерное самомнение, чванство, надменность. Собств.рус. В словарях отмечается с нач. XVIII в. Достоверной этимол. не имеет. Допускается, что соврем. слово развилось из утрач. *спѢсь с изменением Ѣ > е. Само слово* спѢсь, вероятно, образовано параллельно к спѢхъ от глаг. спѢти 'успевать, иметь удачу' и первонач. значило 'успех', откуда дальнейшее - 'чувство достоинства успевшего' > 'гордость' > 'повышенное самомнение'. От сущ. спѢсь с пом. суф. -ив- (как ленивый) образовано прил. спѢсивыи > после изменения о > е, и > и соврем, спесивый 'высокомерный, надменный, чванливый. (Этимологический словарь Цыганенко)